# First WCFservice hit takes time to respond. How to manage idle time of a WCFservice

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have hosted my WCF in a windows service with the following binding configuration. I set the receive timeout for 2 hours 10 mins (just for testing).

```
<wsHttpBinding> 
   <binding name="binding1" transactionFlow="true" receiveTimeout="02:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="32768" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
```

However, after every 20 minutes idle time, the first request being fired takes 5 to 10 seconds extra than the subsequent requests. 
I have also set the usedefaultwebproxy settings of client side binding configurations to false.

Could someone help me, where the idle time out is managed in WCF.

Comment: Are you hosting the WCF under IIS? If so I would check the app pool recycle settings. I have noticed the first call after a app pool recycle is always slightly slower.

Comment: @BossRoss It has been hosted in Windows service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered [to the same question here once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389896/c-sharp-wcf-hosted-in-windows-service-goes-idle-after-5-minutes/33396091#33396091). This is caused by internal ThreadPool management done by WCF, and it requieres some time to warm-up again. Try the hack, which I found once and it really helped a lot.